# How to copy an uninitialized class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, deep-copy

I have this class

```
class TestEvent(object)
    value = None
```

I want to get a duplicate of this class so it isn't referenced but when i try using the copy library the variables are always referenced:

```
>>> clsOne = TestEvent
>>> clsTwo = copy.deepcopy(TestEvent)
>>> clsOne.value = "hello motto"
>>> clsTwo.value
"hello motto"
```

This is also the case with `copy.copy`. Can someone show me how to get a duplicate of this class?

Comment: Could you expand on the context - *why* do you need to create a copy of the class?

Comment: For unit testing. I'm making a class inherited by `unittest.TestResult` to keep track of results in my own way. I want to be able to run multiple of these in using threads, but since this class is always referenced the results end up mixed up.

Comment: But why are you storing attributes on the _class_, and not on _instances_?

Comment: The example was just to the show the issue i'm having, unitttest create a new instance of the class but for some reason it's changes are being referenced back to the class itself. Something i'm not skilled enough to understand yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copy.copy()` and friends will return the value unchanged when you pass a class.

You can use `type()` instead:

```
# shallow copy of the namespace
new_cls = type(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))
```

or:

```
# deep copy of the namespace
new_cls = type(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, copy.deepcopy(dict(cls.__dict__)))
```